# one button accessing the values of other button based on that button's id in android

Tags: android

I have a button in linear layout.

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/m"
                android:gravity="center"/>
```

i need to access the values of width and height of this button, using this button's id as reference.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` by making the button a button object in java code.

Comment: in the main xml, how can we access that ?

Comment: give it an id and access it in your activity or fragment.

Comment: You can't access it's height/weight in xml, only in Java code.

Comment: u can change the values of the height and the width in the xml.

Comment: it want to change it, by referring id of that button

Comment: you can do that in java code but using the setWidth() and setHeight() methods in your activity.

Comment: use setLayoutParams() if you want to programatically change your view